# Find the Cauchy product of $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, exponential-function, cauchy-product

I was able to get to:

$c_n$ = $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{x^k (-x)^{n-k}}{n!}$$
but I am stuck as to how to get past this. Is there a property of the series that lets me pull the negative sign out? I am trying to show that all coefficients aside from $k = 0$ will give me $0$. We are given the hint of Newton's binomial formula, and I presume I will want to have my second term in that be zero, but I am unsure how to show that the numerator of the series is always zero.

Comment: "pull the negative sign out?" $(-x)^m=(-1)^mx^m$.

Comment: Yes, I presume I am allowed to do that?

Comment: Well, $(-x)=(-1)\cdot x$ and $(ab)^m=a^mb^m$ for real numbers $a,b$ and nonnegative integer $m$.

Comment: First of all, we have that $e^x\cdot e^{-x}=1,$ so we know what the $c_n$ must be, right?

Comment: @Sam: are you asked to show by the series *definition* of the exponential function that $e^x\cdot e^{-x}=1$? Otherwise, as Thomas pointed out, the the product of $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ is simply $1$. ([Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) is a concept for infinite series; you may want to edit the title of your post.)

Comment: We are told to use the Cauchy product.

Comment: @Sam: that's what I meant. So your *definition* of the exponential function is  $$e^z:=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}$$ and you are told to prove using this definition (and the Cauchy product) to show that $e^x\cdot e^{-x}=1$ for any real number $x$, correct?

Comment: We were not told that it was equal to 1, we are to prove that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{x^k(-x)^{n-k}}{n!}=x^n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(n-k)!}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $x^k(-x)^{n-k}=(-1)^{n-k}x^n$ and that$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(-1)^k=\bigl(1+(-1)\bigr)^n=0$$if $n>0$.

Comment: Equals $0$ you mean?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout I've edited my answer. Thank you.